# ¿Existe forma de controlar el orden de las migraciones en Laravel?

Tags: laravel

Tengo dos tablas que necesito relacionarlas entre sí pero, al parecer al correr el comando de las migraciones, me crea primeramente la tabla con la llave primaria (en la cuál también se encuentra la llave foránea para la segunda tabla) y luego la otra tabla a la cual quiero relacionar y, por ende, me arroja un error ya que no encuentra el id de la segunda tabla.

Mi duda es que si existe algún comando o método que pueda utilizar para indicar a Laravel el orden en el que quiero que corran mis migraciones, intenté buscando en la documentación pero, lastimosamente, no pude encontrar nada relacionado a eso.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Buen día,

En laravel las migraciónes se ejecutan de acuerdo al orden decendente de los archivos

Normalmente los archivos de las tablas tienen la siguiente estructura
aaaa_mm_dd_hhmmss_create_nombre_de_tabla_table.php

Donde:
aaaa es año a 4 dígitos
mm es mes a 2 dígitos
dd es día a 2 dígitos
hhmmss es hora a 2 dígitos, minutos a 2 dígitos, ss segundos a 2 dígitos

Teniendo 2 tablas:

```
2021_10_22_000001_create_users_table.php
2021_10_26_144554_create_sessions_table.php
```

Siempre se va a procesar primero users y luego sessions

Si deseas cambiar el orden de procesamiento solo debes cambiar el nombre de la tabla "sessions" para que quede arriba de "users"

```
2021_10_20_144554_create_sessions_table.php
2021_10_22_000001_create_users_table.php
```

En el ejemplo anterior cambie de 2021_10_26 a 2021_10_20 el nombre de la tabla "sessions"

La fecha que aparece en el nombre es la fecha de creación del archivo pero en realidad podrías utilizar otro formato para nombrar tus tablas, por ejemplo, podrías utilizar 3 dígitos al inicio de la tabla

```
000_create_sessions_table.php
001_create_users_table.php
```

Lo importante es entender que las tablas van a ser procesadas en orden descendente de acuerdo al nombre del archivo.

Comment: Saludos @HeytalePazguato, excelente, me funcionó perfectamente tu solución y me ayudaste a entender mejor el orden de ejecución de las migraciones, muchas gracias.