# Migración en Laravel 8, no me deja colocar llave foránea en la tabla por defecto de users

Tags: mysql, eloquent, laravel-8, relaciones, migration

Tengo un error al momento de colocar una llave foránea en la tabla de users de laravel.

Tengo la tabla users de laravel, y la quiero relacionar a la tabla de employees, la cual tendrá los datos personales de los empleados, pero al intentar poner la llave foránea dentro de la tabla users, me da error:

> *PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `name_data_base`.`users` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")")*

Este error solo me da en esta relación, ya que tengo más tablas y no me da problema.

Este es el código de las dos tablas:

**Tabla de employees**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('employees', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->foreignId('person_id')->references('id')->on('people');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

**Tabla de users**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->foreignId('employee_id')->references('id')->on('employees');
    });
}
```

Comment: y dónde estás creando la columna `employee_id` ? De paso, existe siquiera la tabla  `people`?

Comment: @ffflabs **employee_id** la estoy creando en la tabla users, pretendiendo ser la llave foránea de la tabla **employees**, ya que teniendo una lista de empleados, se pueda crear un usuario a un empleado si se desea. Pero me da error. Cabe destacar que ya probé hacer la relación al contrario, colocando una llave foránea en la tabla **employees**, referenciando a **users**, y en dicho caso si funciona, pero sigo pensando que lo más adecuado sería tener la llave foránea en **users**

Comment: No estoy de acuerdo con el diseño, pero lo importante para sortear el error, en este caso, es que te falta declarar `$table->int('employee_id')`. No se crea automáticamente por declarar una FK

Comment: Buen día, lo que puede estar pasando es que el orden de tus migraciones está interfiriendo en la creación de la relación, si la tabla users se crea antes que employees entonces te va a mandar error, revisa [ésta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/507828/171630) para cambiar el orden de tus migraciones